# How to create a Plone 4 group who's sole purpose is to manage users?

Tags: permissions, plone, roles

I'm trying to set up a Plone group (`Plone 4.0.7`) that will be responsible purely for creating and amending users. I don't want them to have full admin access to the site, purely to the `Users and Groups` functionality.

I have created a role in `my.package/profiles/default/rolemap.xml` like so:

```
<role name="Maintain Users" />
```

and then added a permission thus:

```
<permission name="Manage users" acquire="false">
    <role name="Maintain Users" />
    <role name="Manager" />
</permission>
```

In `my.package/setuphandlers.py` I have added a new group that uses the role:

```
groups = {
    ....
    'Service Desk': ['Maintain Users', 'Member'],
    ....
}
```

I am able to add users to my newly created `Service Desk` group, so I'm confident that works, but what I'm not getting is the ability for users in that group to be able to Maintain Users.

I naively expected there to be an option on the menu (similar to 'Site Setup') once they had logged in, this is not the case.

What additional steps do I need to take to be able to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You have to grant these 2 permissions to your custom role:

- `Plone Site Setup: Overview` (for the menu entry and the access to the control panel)
- `Plone Site Setup: Users and Groups` (for the permission to manage users and groups)

Comment: Giacomo, I've managed to get the permission working which is a major step in the right direction!

The only issue is the `Overview` option that doesn't appear to enable the menu and so the only way the user can get to the Manage Users and Groups screen is to suffix the URL with `@@user-group-userprefs`

Comment: Check the permission in <yoursite>/portal_actions/user/plone_setup/manage_propertiesForm - it was changed in 4.1 from `Manage portal` to `Plone Site Setup: Overview`. An upgrade step should have sorted this out for you, but it's possible it didn't work somehow.