# Delegating Plone managing users and local roles on content

Tags: plone, roles

We are using Plone 4.2.2 and we would like to delegate user account/group creation and managing local roles on content to our tier 1 helpdesk folks. We initially thought to use the Site Administrator role and just add the Site Setup Overview and Site Setup Users and Groups permissions. This allows them to create users and groups, but they don't have access to the sharing tab to manage local roles on folder and file objects.

I'm not finding much help out there and this seems like it would be a fairly common delegation. In fact, I'm surprised there isn't a role specifically for this. Giving Manager role to our tier 1 is a little scary.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I found this thread that referenced Managing Users, but not the local roles on content
[How to create a Plone 4 group who's sole purpose is to manage users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8245484/how-to-create-a-plone-4-group-whos-sole-purpose-is-to-manage-users)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The access to the sharing tab is only about permission.

You must give to your users the "`Sharing page: Delegate roles`" and all needed permission named "Sharing page: Delegate *XXX* role".

But to be honest I think that the Site Administrator role already have all those power you need.

Comment: This is a case of looking at the page so many times that you don't see what you're looking at. I did not see these sharing permissions and I went up and down the list a few times.  I'm comparing our new,clean plone install with a demo appliance we got from the great guys at Six Feet Up and our users with the Site Administrator role do not have access to the Site Setup and Sharing pages by default, but on their appliance, they do. We're not sue why there is a difference, so we're sorting that out now.

Comment: I've wrote some documentation about this, but is for italian users only... http://plone-worfklow-e-sicurezza.readthedocs.org/en/latest/permissions.html#sharing-page :)

Answer (score 2):

What I would do is that instead of using the normal Plone user manager I'd

- write a custom, simplified, user management form in Python add-on
- form does sanity checks by allowing creating only of certain kind of users with certain roles
- form also can delegate setting local roles on folders programmatically (no need to go to Sharing tab)
- expose this form through a special new permission
- Give the permission for the form to Tier 1 support personnel

As the use case is very specialized it might be easier to write your own manager form than customizing existing Plone logic.